# how to set leaflet marker to center of div tag in leafletjs

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want the marker to be in the center of the map, but it is wrong.
I read the rest of the articles, but my problem was not solved.

```js
 var map = L.map('map').setView([lat, lng], 18);

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox.streets',
    accessToken: 'pk',
    attribution: 'nemajoo',
    watch: true
}).addTo(map);
var LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {

        iconSize:     [28, 60],
        shadowSize:   [50, 64],
        iconAnchor:   [22, 94],
        shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
        popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]
    }
});
var greenIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: 'images/mrk.png'});
var center = map.getCenter();
var marker = L.marker([center.lat, center.lng],{icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: What do you mean *exactly* by "it is wrong"? What's the actual result vs the expected result?

Comment: @IvanSanchez I want the marker to be exactly in the middle of the map, but here the marker is not centered on the map.

Comment: The marker image doesn't have zero size. You need to be *even more* specific. Which part of the marker needs to align with the center of the map canvas?

Comment: @IvanSanchez I do not understand your meaning. I want the marker to be displayed exactly in the middle.

Comment: Do you want to align the bottom of the marker to the center of the image, or do you want to align the center of the marker to the center of the image?

Comment: @IvanSanchez  I want to align the bottom of the marker to the center of the map

Comment: Adjust your `iconAnchor` to the height of the `iconSize`. I wonder how you ended up with those values.

Comment: @IvanSanchez  Closer but has not yet reached the center.  `var LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {

        iconSize:     [26, 40],
        iconAnchor:   [26, 40],
    }
});
var greenIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: 'images/mrk.png'});
var center = map.getCenter();
var marker = L.marker([center.lat, center.lng],{icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map);
`

Answer (score 1):

The problem here could be in any of the 3 configurations given we don't have the image:

- *mrk.png* has some **spacing inside the image**, this can be fixed with any image editing tool.
- the options object, on the **anchor tag *moves* the image**, making it look like it's not centered.
- When you set the center, as far as I can see, you first get the center from the map, then use this center to position the icon, this is nicely done but **markers with distant zooming don't represent it's center accurately**.

In resume:
The problem is on the **png** or the **anchor configuration**, modify those values and try again.

If this does not work you can upload a sample minimal project so we can check (don't upload api keys or similar)

Comment: Image mrk.png is correct in terms of size and spacing.
You can send a sample code. I really tried a lot.

Comment: @ho3ein I can help if you offer a code sample that represents your problem